# systemctl --user enable won't create directories, errors as a result

Tags: permissions, systemd, systemd-user

Whenever I run `systemctl --user enable <some-unit>`, it complains:

```
/xdg/config/home/systemd/user/<install-section.wants-or-requires>/<some-unit>.service does not exist
```

to which my initial reaction was Well no, you're (`enable`) supposed to create it, but specifically it turns out it's referring to the parent directory; it works fine if I make sure `<install-section.wants-or-requires>` exists first.

I would expect this directory to be created as required - `systemctl` system-wide does, and it's not like there's a bounded set of wants/requires directories to be created once by a user and then done.

Is this a bug, or a permissions problem? My `/xdg/config/home/systemd/user` directory is `0755`, owned by my user (and default user group).